# How to make best use of only good sectors/partitions on a semi-faulty HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure, bad-sectors

Some time ago, I've been given a Toshiba 1TB external USB drive for free.
The reason for this giveaway was that the drive allegedly stops copying/reading at random and is therefore too faulty to use. In reality, it turned out to be a bit more interesting than just "drive bad, replace".

**TLDR Questions:**
[Drive Partition map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pgmu.png)

1. "GOOD" partitions are spread out, and the sector space is unevenly distributed between them. BAD partitions are unusable. Neither can be moved due to platter damage (offsets are fixed). Is there a way to merge the "GOOD" space into one partition while keeping the MBR (not GPT) drive type? Even if it will result in "GOOD" partition being fully logical.
2. IF not, what could be the alternative?

**Long version with the tests and research is below:**

Naturally, I've decided to perform some basic diagnostics:

1. First, the drive was disassembled and connected via SATA to eliminate the possibility of USB-to-SATA board being the culprit.
2. Second, reading the SMART data showed that value for the parameter 005:Reallocation Sector Count is very high (16376), with C4: Reallocated Event Count being 334.

Normally, after seeing this (and even hearing a BIOS warning: "SMART status bad") I'd consider the drive toast, backup what's possible and get a replacement.
However, after researching on SMART, I've realized how generalist, vague SMART data readings could be, potentially not reflecting the actual state of the hardware.

Therefore, I've decided to run additional tests, using:

- HDTunePRO
- HDDscan
- Manual copy-pasting onto drive
- Windows format (full, not quick)
- Windows DSKMGMT console

**Test Results:**

- HDTunePRO hangs 10 seconds into error scan routine, then crashes the drive into unreadability until power-cycled.
- HDDscan drive read/write test returns "Test was interrupted by software/hardware". Butterfly seek and random write tests are passed, so I conclude that the mechanical subsystem and write head are in good condition.
- Manually copying the files produced conflicting results:

  --Small (1-1000 mb) files were copied very fast without any problem.

  --Large files (2-4gb+) would stop copying at some point and crash the drive into inaccessible state until power-cycled.
  --Filling the drive with small files until certain point (4gb or so) would prevent any further writing. Any attempts to copy more files would crash the drive.
- Windows format utility hangs at some point and displays a warning that the drive may be faulty, offering to make a backup.

**Conclusions so far:** "HARD" bad blocks are present at certain memory offsets on the drive. For some reason, they were not reallocated by drive's firmware and any attempts to access those blocks hang the drive's firmware. Additional testing is needed to gauge how bad the damage is and how much of the drive's space is actually usable.

I've decided to "probe" the drive using Windows' Disk Management console. The drive was first cleaned (DISKPART CLEAN), then "probed" by:

1. Create a partition 10GB in size.
2. "FULL" formatting ("Quick format" checkbox unchecked). AFAIK this will write zeroes to the partition and verify read/write.
3. IF Full formatting is unsuccessful, name the partition as "BAD", go to Step 1.
4. IF Full formatting succeeds, name the partition as "GOOD", go to Step 1.

By spending some time doing this back-and-forth partitioning with merging the "GOOD" parts, I've eventually arrived at the following "drive map":
[Drive "map"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqGvX.png)

Testing the "GOOD" partitions yielded great results: files, even very large ones, were copied at very high rates (130MB/sec+), repeated writes yielded no errors.
Connecting SATA-to-USB board resulted in no issues whatsoever.

I could use extra 800+ GB of free storage, if only for non-critical data. Questions are:

1. "GOOD" partitions are spread out, and the sector space is unevenly distributed between them. BAD partitions are unusable. Neither can be moved due to platter damage (offsets are fixed). Is there a way to merge the "GOOD" space into one partition while keeping the MBR (not GPT) drive type? Even if it will result in "GOOD" partition being fully logical.
2. If not, what could be the alternative?

Comment: Why waste time and effort on a drive that is failing?  Hard disk drives are *cheap*.  Just replace it.

Comment: The thing is, you can't even tell whether there are only a few sectors that are bad and more importantly, whether it will stay that way as you continue to use it. (Often it won't.) It could even be other parts inside the disk that are breaking down.

Comment: @TomYan Agreed. However, it may also be a manufacturing defect or one-time impact -caused damage on the platters that bottlenecks otherwise very useable drive. I'd like to see if that can be the case too, hence all this effort. As I've full-formatted (wrote zeroes) to the GOOD partitions numerous times without any issues, I believe this may be the case here.

Comment: Anyway, you need something like LVM in Linux to "merge" discrete partitions. (On Windows the closest thing might be Storage Space, but as usual Windows poses quite a few silly / pointless restrictions IIRC, so just find out yourself if you can use it for your drive.)

Comment: @TomYan I have a Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) laptop. Tried GParted, however it has the same issue as Windwos DSKMGMT - partitions must be adjacent. Any guides/links on how to do the non-adj merge?

Comment: The solution under linux cannot be used under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

> However, after researching on SMART, I've realized how generalist,
> vague SMART data readings could be, potentially not reflecting the
> actual state of the hardware.

What is your reference your dubious judgement is based upon?!

> Second, reading the SMART data showed that value for the parameter
> 005:Reallocation Sector Count is very high (16376), with C4:
> Reallocated Event Count being 334.

There is nothing generalist with the SMART values you have given. These values are specific. This is what your drive keeps in his own bookkeeping.
"Vague" is by the way true for those readings as as the dammage could be already much bigger. The figures given are only a lower boundary for the current status which may be already worse.

Labeling those partitions "GOOD" is an euphemism as is your effort to downplay the state of dammage your drive is in.

Answer (score 0):

> Reallocation Sector Count is very high (16376)

That's quite a lot indeed. It's enough to stop anyone from reading the rest and reach the IMO only sane conclusion: Trash this totally unreliable drive, don't bother working around current errors.

Any error you encounter during all your experiments comes *on top* of those already reallocated sectors.

I treat SMART like this: If SMART says all is well then still your drive could fail within the next five minutes. If SMART on the other hand gives you all kinds of warming then better take those seriously. 16376 reallocated sectors is like it's screaming to you, stop using this drive!